# Cordex precipatation values reproject to WGS84 from Lampert Conical

Tags: coordinate-system, rioxarray, lambert-conformal-conic

I have to calculate some precipitation indices for a region, and for this I have to reproject the dataset to WGS84. I have the following code to obtain the datasets:

```
import cdsapi
import rioxarray as rioxr
import os
#download datasets from copernicus climate data store
c = cdsapi.Client()

for rcp in ['rcp_2_6','rcp_4_5','rcp_8_5']:
    for start in range(2021,2101,10):
        c.retrieve(
            'projections-cordex-domains-single-levels',
            {
                'format': 'zip',
                'domain': 'europe',
                'experiment': 'rcp_2_6',
                'horizontal_resolution': '0_11_degree_x_0_11_degree',
                'temporal_resolution': 'monthly_mean',
                'variable': 'mean_precipitation_flux',
                'gcm_model': 'cnrm_cerfacs_cm5',
                'rcm_model': 'cnrm_aladin63',
                'ensemble_member': 'r1i1p1',
                'start_year': str(start),
                'end_year': str(start+9),
            },
            'precip_'+rcp+'_'+str(start)+'.zip')

# after unziping I just put the netcdf files on a list named nc_2_6

ncfolder_2_6 = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\....\cordex_rcp_2_6')

_files = [file for file in os.listdir(ncfolder_2_6) if file.endswith('.nc')]

all_datasets=[]

for file in _files:
    ds = rioxr.open_rasterio(file)
    precip = ds[1] #for some reason there are 3 datasets in each file
    all_datasets.append(precip)

da = xarray.merge([ds for ds in all_datasets]) #merges them along the time dimension and I end up with a dataset with 960 monthly precipation maps
```

Now, I check the spatial reference of the dataset with `da.pr.spatial_ref` to get:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'spatial_ref' ()>
array(0)
Coordinates:
    Lambert_Conformal  int32 0
    spatial_ref        int32 0
Attributes:
    GeoTransform:  -6.25 12.5 0.0 5656.25 0.0 -12.5
```

My question is how to reproject to WGS84?
With `da.rio.reproject("EPSG:4326")` it fails with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[28], line 1
    da.rio.reproject("EPSG:4326")

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\drought_study\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\raster_dataset.py:116 in reproject
    self._obj[var]

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\drought_study\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\raster_array.py:445 in reproject
    raise MissingCRS(

MissingCRS: CRS not found. Please set the CRS with 'rio.write_crs()'. Data variable: pr
```

How can I write this strange Lambert_Conformal projection into a CRS? The other attributes are:

```
Lambert_Conformal#grid_mapping_name:              lambert_conformal_conic
Lambert_Conformal#latitude_of_projection_origin:  49.5
Lambert_Conformal#longitude_of_central_meridian:  10.5
Lambert_Conformal#standard_parallel:              49.5
```